# Xcode git structure issues

Tags: git

Using Xcode with Swift and git I have a strange behavior. It looks like all my files are saved under the same XcodeProjects repository which contains my .git folder and when I am in a Xcode project (for instance projectA) under project navigator I see correctly my ProjectA with all my swift files but when selecting "show the soucre control navigator" button I get automatically the XcodeProjects folder and not my ProjectA folder.
I believe it has something to do with the way I have setup git on Xcode. Any idea how I can get back to a clean structure when selecting ProjectA under source control I stay on this individual project.

Comment: Please be aware that the .git folder _is_ the repository.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know. So I have a related question to that how can I restore a snapshot of a backup by searching in this .git repository? I changed today something in gits and I can not find back a snapshot and in addition it discarded all files of some projects, how is it possible?? I have some folders but they are empty like Pods, Controller, the only file which remain in my project folder is myproject.xcworkspace

Comment: Honestly I don't really understand the question.

Comment: Rephrasing it: git purpose is to record snapshots of projects at a certain time. I want to recover some snapshots I recorded under git but I cannot retrieve them via xcode (due to an issue that doesn't allow me to find them back). I believe the snapshots are still existing in .git so my question is how would it be possible to dig directly in .git folder to restore such saved snapshots.

Comment: Use git in the terminal? Try not to edit the files inside the .git folder as you could end up corrupting the repo